# Stop razor inline code-block within attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I want to achieve the following:

```
<input id="HtmlFieldPrefix_enterParentButton" type="button" value="Enter" />
```

I started off with:

```
<input id="@ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix-enterParentButton" type="button" value="Enter"/>
```

which works perfectly, however, notice I used a dash instead of an underscore. If I switch to an underscore I receive an error: Razor thinks "_enterParentButton" is part of the C# code. How to stop the razor parsing before the underscore?

In other words, how to fix this line to behave as expected:

```
<input id="@ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix_enterParentButton" type="button" value="Enter"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Embrace it with parenthesis:

```
@(ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix)


<input id="@(ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix)_enterParentButton" type="button" value="Enter"/>
```

Comment: Simple as that, thanks! I'll mark as answered as soon as SO allows me to :-)

Comment: Yes it is...I' ve been there too and i know how frustrating is when you are trying to achieve something but you get annoying errors....